# Count nodes with only one child in a Binary Search Tree?

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree

How should I count the nodes with only one child in a Binary Search Tree?

```
def one_child_count(self):

    node = self._root
    count = self.one_child_count_aux(node)
    return count
def one_child_count_aux(self,node):
    count = 0
    if node :
        if node._left is not  None and  node._right is None: 

            count += 1
        if node._right is not  None and  node._left is None: 

            count += 1

        else:
            if node._left: 
                count += self.leaf_count_aux(node._left) 
            if node._right: 
                count += self.leaf_count_aux(node._right) 
    return count
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong. When I try to run my code and insert:

```
bst.insert(37)
bst.insert(12)
```

with tree being like:

```
  37
 /
12
```

it should return 1 but I get 2.  Help me correct my code, please.

Comment: What is `leaf_count_aux`?

Comment: I am sorry I spotted this mistake Thanks for pointing out  @Adam Smith its working now :) that was a foolish mistake tho

Answer (score 0):

If you're using recursion anyway, you can use a general recursive function that will count one- *or* two-child nodes.

```
def count_nodes(bst):
    def count_nodes2(node):
        if node is None:
            return 0
        return 1 + count_nodes2(node._left) + count_nodes2(node._right)

    return count_nodes2(bst._root)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are *two* problems with your code: first, there's a logic error in your `if` statements with respect to using an `else`; second you're calling the unshown function `leaf_count_aux()`, making this not recursive, instead of calling `one_child_count_aux()` recursively.  My guess is you want something more like:

```
def one_child_count(self):
    node = self._root
    count = self.one_child_count_aux(node)
    return count

def one_child_count_aux(self, node):
    count = 0

    if node:
        if node._left is not None:
            if node._right is None:
                count += 1

            count += self.one_child_count_aux(node._left)

        if node._right is not None:
            if node._left is None:
                count += 1

            count += self.one_child_count_aux(node._right)

    return count
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `getattr` for a much cleaner recursive function:

```
class Tree:
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.__dict__ = {i:kwargs.get(i) for i in ['val', '_left', '_right']}
  def count_nodes(self):
    yield 1
    yield from getattr(self._left, 'count_nodes', lambda :[])()
    yield from getattr(self._right, 'count_nodes', lambda :[])()

t = Tree(_left = Tree(val = 12), val = 37)
result = sum(t.count_nodes())
```

Output:

```
2
```